# 201 status node express API always failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

I am trying to make an api through express. However, the response from the server i am getting is `201 created`. The HTTP request i am trying to make through promises is interpreting the `then` process as false and it continually goes through a failed criteria.

Any idea on how i can get `201 created` through the example below.

**Example:** The output even while being successful automatically goes through error status.

```
router.get('/example', session, function (req, res) {
    example(req.body, req.session.token).then(
        (response) => {
            res.json(response);
        },
        (err) => {
            if (err.status) {
                res.status(err.status).json({
                    status: err.status,
                    message: err.message
                });
            } else {
                res.status(constants.HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
                    status: constants.HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    message: 'Internal Server Error'
                });
            }
        }
    );
});

module.exports.example = (body, token) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const mainToken = createRawToken(token);
        request.post(
            {
                url: `${endpoint}`,
                body: JSON.stringify(body),
                headers: {
                    Authorization: mainToken,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            },
            (error, response, bdy) => {
                resolve(requestService.handleResponse(error, response, bdy, constants.HTTP_OK));
            }
        );
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is in the `example` function. The promise seems fine but i am assuming that you're naming your constants well.

`constants.HTTP_OK` should be `constants.HTTP_CREATED`. Behind them i am assuming that `HTTP_OK` is `200` and `HTTP_CREATED` should be `201`.